# Excel Max Length of each column data

Tags: excel, maxlength

Simple one for someone hopefully. I'm trying to get the max length of each column in an excel sheet but it doesn't seem to be working now. I was using =MAX(LEN(A2:A200)) for example and because MAX is not an "official" formula but is still there you seem to have to press CTRL + ALT + SHIFT once you have finished typing it.

When I do this it puts curly brackets round the whole formula like this {=MAX(LEN(A2:A200))} but if I click into the cell they disappear. the length of the first column will appear but then if I autofill to the next column it shows same length of column data from the first column rather than calculating the next column.

Perhaps not a straight up programming question but scratching my head why this is not working now. I'm trying to show max length of each column above header column in new row.

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 10):

In **A1** enter the **array formula**:

```
=MAX(LEN(A2:A200))
```

then ***stop clicking***.

Move to **A1** with the ARROW keys.  Touch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. Then paste to **B2** through **G2** using  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>:

[image]

This will put the array formula in the destination cells.

Comment: I tried this and it does the same thing. All columns taking same length of the first one.

Comment: Actually I thought this still wasn't working. I went away and tried another workbook, came back and it had calculated the max length of the cells. My worksheet has about 180 columns but I tried about 5 to see if it was working. Still waiting to see if it calculates all the columns.

Edit: I found out that I need to save the workbook to activate it for some strange reason?

Comment: Also noticed some of the formulas say #NAME? instead of a max length value.

Comment: @Andrew, the #NAME? is probably due to specifying wrong start cell for the range, e.g. A1 which, in this case, would cause a circular ref. error.

Answer (score 8):

Use Gary's formula and instead of ENTER, do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

> When I do this it puts curly brackets round the whole formula like this {=MAX(LEN(A2:A200))} but if I click into the cell they disappear. the length of the first column will appear but then if I autofill to the next column it shows same length of column data from the first column rather than calculating the next column.

It is right to use formulas with brackets (they are called [Matrix formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)). The brackets disappears because when you edit the content of the cell you have to push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and not only <kbd>Enter</kbd> like normal formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume all your data is in **Sheet1** starting at cell **A1**.

1. Create **Sheet2**
2. Enter the `=LEN(Sheet1!A1)` formula in cell **A1** on **Sheet2**
3. Pull **Sheet2**'s **A1** cell down/over to the right to cover the populated
   range of **Sheet1** (to copy the formula to every cell of the range in
   scope) - this will give you the length of every cell in scope
4. Enter the `=MAX(A1:A10)` formula on **Sheet2** in the first column below
   the last line (**A10** is assumed to be the last line of the first
   column in this example - so the formula goes in **A11**)
5. Pull **Sheet2**'s **A11** cell over to the right till the last column to get
   the MAX length of values for each column